# How to acheive background animition like the page has given below

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the link:
[danielcoding.me/resume/#contact](http://danielcoding.me/resume/#contact)

I want this animition :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFw4k.png)

I inspect element on this page , but there is no pics as background, I found nothing.
How to create this animition ?
Is it made only by javascript or css?
Are there more example like this animition?
I really like this style , I want to study more

Comment: This isn't a coding service; please post what you have tried and what didn't work about it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they're using something like [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js), a pretty cool jQuery plugin. Pretty simple to setup, check out the demos they have.

Comment: Thank you! I found the way to make this effect here: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/